# Doubling bandwidth with 2 ISPs

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, bandwidth

For about another week I'll be connected to 2 providers simultaneously from home.

I thought this could be a great time to double my bandwidth (I have ADSL + HSDPA) thanks to the fact that my computer has 2 cards, each connected to one of the routers.

I'm simply excited about the idea that I could use JDownloader to download twice faster.

The problem is that even if both connections are active, Windows **always** prefers 1 network card, specifically the HSDPA router that is currently connected over a Gigabit ethernet cable instead of the ADSL (5Mbit/s) connected over a regular 100Mbit Ethernet.

Do you know a way to tell Windows (or eMule and JDownloader separately) to open connections on both hardware network cards for any destination and balance traffic instead of preferring a single card only?

Comment: OK I said "doubling" in my title. I know that HSDPA + ADSL != 2xHSDPA but I gave the idea ;-)

Comment: do you have a router? what is the brand/model? Routers decide the path, computers/switches/hubs do not.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+routing

Comment: @Logman I have a TP-Link wireless router connected to ADSL and to card 2 of my Windows host, **and** a Huawei router provided by my second ISP with a backup USB dongle inserted in it (in case ADSL doesn't work). The TP-Link router has only 1 WAN interface, so there is no routing choice ;-)

Comment: Lookup changing metrics. I'm on my cell so I can't describe it enough to be an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't try it out myself since I don't have a second internet connection at hand, but [OCTOPUS+](http://www.octopusplus.com/) seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

From [their about page](http://www.octopusplus.com/example.jsp):

> [...] OCTOPUS+ will help in utilizing all the active internet connections available in a computer. OCTOPUS+ will intelligently manage the traffic between a computer and the internet among the available active internet connections. [...]

This should automatically boost all multipart downloads.

A license costs USD 29.99, but you can download a [free 30-day trial from CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Octopus/3000-2381_4-75329730.html).

Answer (score 0):

Manual way for JDownloader, just for the sake of sharing (I won't accept this answer)

In general, when you are connected to 2 ISPs with 1 favourite by Windows: disconnect favourite provider, start downloads (you need a premium account to start multiple downloads), once they are started connect the other card and from JDownloader windows double the number of concurrent downloads/connection.

It helped me go from 315KBps to 800KBps+

Comment: If there is no better answer over the next couple of days, there is nothing wrong with accepting your own answer.

Comment: I don't like "manual ways of doing things" :-)

Comment: You can offer a bounty, but I'd wait.