# Simultaneous use of internet connections

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I know this has been asked a lot of times but I'm asking this again to see if there are any new solutions available.

I have a motherboard with two network adapters;

> [image]

I have a DSL connection with my landline which I've been using till now. I've taken a new fiber connection from a different ISP.

I wanted to know if there is a way I can utilize both connections at the same time? I've read about ForceBind and using VM's but the solutions are quite old.

Are there any new solutions for it?

Comment: Can you please link us to the other questions where this was supposedly asked before? In order to attract attention to an old question, we have other methods than just "posting a new one".

Comment: Related: [Doubling bandwidth with 2 ISPs](http://superuser.com/q/435007)

Answer (score 1):

Linux has some great software to do this, it s mostly for load balancing on a server.

As @Dave Rook says, dual Wan router would work. I use [Untangle](http://www.untangle.com/)